# Values of an integer array to be transformed to one integer

Tags: arrays, c

```
int ImportValues()
{
    int firstly=ImportValue_1();
    int secondtly=ImportValue_2();
    int thirdtly=ImportValue_3();
    int fourthly=ImportValue_4();
    //importing the values, to the array
     int array[4]={firstly,secondtly,thirdtly,fourthly};
    //Because we want, to specify the memory adress, of the array, we type down(&array[0])
    printArray(&array[0]);
    ValuesOfArrayAsaOneInteger(&array[0]);
    return 0;
}


void printArray(int* array)
{
    int i;
    //printing the values of the array//
    printf("The values of the array is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        printf("[%d] is %d\n", i, array[i]);
      
    }
}
void ValuesOfArrayAsaOneInteger(int*array)
{
    //message, which will give the user a complete image of the integer.
}
```

I'm trying to create a program in which the user will give me a 8 digit integer
and I will give them the opportunity to find out if this integer can be divided
by the numbers 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. Because the integer the user will give me is very large number, I thought I could split it in four parts, import these four parts in an array and afterwards this array to be represented to the user, as well as the compiler to see this array as a one integer. How can I do that?

Comment: On most platforms these days, sizeof(int) >= 4, and a 4 byte unsigned value can go as large as 2^32-1 = 4294967295 which is 10 digits. In your question, you propose to split an 8 digit integer into 4 pieces (of two digits each presumably). Your approach is possible but seems unnecessary for such a small number. If you really want to deal with the number in small chunks, consider reading it in character by character instead and handling all the digits individually?

Comment: In terms of your code, it would be helpful to edit your post to include a paste of the code between two lines each of which have triple backquotes so that it comes out nicely formatted. Your image is hard to read and won't exist forever.

Comment: The value &array[0] == array. So it is simpler to not index and then take the address.

Comment: If you know that each piece is 2 digits, you can do the following loop: `for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { printf("%02d", array[i]) } printf("\n");`

Comment: Thank you very much, for you answer as well as, the tips you have gave me, i really appreciate it. I will try, some of the the tips you gave me. I am sorry for the image, at first i didn't want to upload an image,but when i tried to post a code snippet,i was having an error message.

Comment: i just saw the last message, thank you, i will try it and i am gonne inform you, how this programm performs. Ευχαριστώ παρα πολύ, για όλα τα info.

Comment: Alex Nicolaou at first point, i managed to upload the code. I will do, everything you have suggested me to do.